# Counting recursive calls of a function

Tags: python, recursion

I have recursive code for generating the Catalan numbers.

I managed to write the recursive call, but for some reason, the counter is not working properly.

For example, the number of calls for the 7th Catalan number should be 1215.

The return value needs to be a tuple of the Catalan number and the number of calls, for example: (429,1215).

Original code:

```
def catalan_rec(n):
    if n<=1:
        return 1
    res=0
    for i in range(n):
        res+=catalan_rec(i)*catalan_rec(n-i-1)
    return res
```

Counter code:

```
def catalan_rec_count(n,counter=1):
    if n<=1:
        return 1
    res=0
    for i in range(n):
        res+=catalan_rec_count(i,counter+1)*catalan_rec_count(n-i-1,counter+1)        
    return (res,counter)
```

Comment: You appear to be returning a number, `res`, not a tuple.

Comment: How do you implement both pieces of code? Show an example of you using the functions, the output you get, and the output you want.

Comment: Yeah, pasted the wrong code.

Comment: Where is the code of you implementing the function?

Comment: Note that `catalan_rec_count(i,counter+1)*catalan_rec_count(n-i-1,counter+1)` is multiplying two tuples together.

Comment: @CharlesMorris, There is not much in it, the first code returns the value of the nth catalan number, the counting code should return a tuple of the nth number and the number of calls, the problem is the 2nd code is not working after trying many varations.

Comment: @Max, I know, that is one of the reasons I need your help, I am a bit lost with it.'

Comment: @CharlesMorris that is called recursion. I think it is intentional.

Comment: @CharlesMorris, nop, its the recursive call.

Comment: @Mor Apologies, one learns something new everyday!

Comment: Wait, so do you want to sum all of the `counter`s? Or the amount of recursive calls?

Comment: @Max, the amount of recursive calls. The number of times the function was called/used.

Answer (score 10):

python allows you to attach a variable (`catalan.counter` in the snippet below) to the function object, so you don't have to pass the counter along all the time and don't need a global variable:

```
def catalan(n):

    catalan.counter += 1

    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    res = 0
    for i in range(n):
        res += catalan(i) * catalan(n-i-1)
    return res

catalan.counter = 0

print(catalan(5))
print(catalan.counter)
```

and seeing that the function is called several times with the same arguments: for more efficiency you could use the [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache); but this of course defeats the purpose of counting how many times the function was called; you'd only get the number the function was called with a *unique* `n`.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def catalan(n):

    ...
```

---

this may be a bit off-topic... but in case you need separate instances of the function with separate counters, a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) might be just what you need:

```
def make_catalan():

    counter = 0

    def catalan(n):

        nonlocal counter
        counter += 1
        catalan.counter = counter

        if n <= 1:
            return 1
        res = 0
        for i in range(n):
            res += catalan(i) * catalan(n-i-1)
        return res

    return catalan

catalan_1 = make_catalan()
print(catalan_1(2))
print(catalan_1.counter)

catalan_2 = make_catalan()
print(catalan_2(3))
print(catalan_2.counter)
```

Comment: I don't think the closure would be necessary, just an internal function that is used in the recursion and a public version that resets it and returns it along with the result in a tuple.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen : i was trying to make a version where you do not have to pass the counter along. resetting would work with my first variant already; but with the closure you can call both functions independently and they keep their own count. but i agree; it is overkill!

Answer (score 5):

You need to seperate out the line `res+=catalan_rec_count(i,counter+1)*catalan_rec_count(n-i-1,counter+1)` so that it can do operations with the recursive results and the counters seperately, so just split it up into a few extra lines, also in this case you wouldn't pass `counter+1` to the recursive calls so that it tracks it's calls independant to the current frame..

```
def catalan_rec_count(n,counter=1):
    if n<=1:
        return (1, counter) #remember to return the counter in this case too!
    res=0
    for i in range(n):
        #get the recursive results and counters for both calls
        #don't pass counter+1 to it, it should count how many times it is called on it's own
        partial1, inner_c1 = catalan_rec_count(i)
        partial2, inner_c2 = catalan_rec_count(n-i-1)
        #apply the logic with the actual result and add to the counter
        res+=partial1*partial2
        counter+= inner_c1 + inner_c2
    return (res,counter)
```

Comment: I was just about to post the counter returns a wrong number. and your comment gave me a good laugh ;)

Comment: It quite surprised me how quickly I got upvoted, anyway I do recommend [@hiro protagonist's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41203348/5827215) over my own (was going to edit in that method in my answer) since it means you can track the counter without needing to deal with splitting out the return value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great, and actually yours is more suited to my needs because it uses the counter as defined in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a decorator for the function you want to track calls on. When the decorator function is called, it increments its internal call count, passes arguments to the tracked function and returns the decorated function's result to its caller.

This way, there's no need to make any adjustments to the function's internals, parameters or return type or use globals--just decorate and roll.

```py
import functools


def count_calls(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.calls += 1
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.calls = 0
    return wrapper


if __name__ == "__main__":

    @count_calls
    def catalan_rec(n):
        if n <= 1:
            return 1
        res = 0
        for i in range(n):
            res += catalan_rec(i) * catalan_rec(n - i - 1)
        return res

    print(catalan_rec(n=7))  # => 429
    print(catalan_rec.calls)  # => 1215
```