# Counting instances of N in an array using Recursion in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to count the number of instances of a given number N in an array using recursion. For example, given:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 8, 1]
```

and `N = 1`, the function should return `5`.

This problem can be solved using the `.counter` attribute as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203214/counting-recursive-calls-of-a-function). However, I am looking to **not** use any in-built functions or attributes.

Here's my attempt to solve this using recursion but I get a count of `1` and not `5`. What am I doing wrong?

```
def count_val(array, n, count=0):
    if len(array) == 0:
        return None
    # Base Case
    if len(array) == 1:
        if array[0] == n:
            count += 1
    else:
        count_val(array[1:], n, count)
        if array[0] == n:
            count += 1
    return count

print(count_val2(array, 1))

1
```

Comment: Recursion is not wise for this problem. Your taking up stack for no reason and it will take longer. Do it in O(n) using a dict or just a simple count with a `for` loop, basically what a from collections import counter does. Also `[1:]` uses splicing,  `[]` uses `__getitem__`, and `len()` uses `__len__` which are all class builtins so why are you just limiting yourself on a few things?

Comment: Interesting, this is something I had not thought of! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for an empty array, the value should be `0` (`len == 0` should be the base case), and, you don't need to have a `count` parameter if you just return the count, your function could be reduced to this:

```
def count_val(array, n):
    if len(array) == 0:
        return 0
    return (array[0] == n) + count_val(array[1:], n)

array = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 8, 1]

print(count_val(array, 1))
```

Output:

```
5
```

You can have it as a one-liner as well (as suggested by @blhsing):

```
def count_val(array, n):
    return len(array) and (array[0] == n) + count_val(array[1:], n)
```

Comment: If you want a one-liner in the function, `return len(array) and (array[0] == n) + count_val(array[1:], n)` will do.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

The function you wrote will always keep only the last few characters, so after a while it will be `[1, 8, 1]`, after that `[8, 1]` and after that `[1]`, which returns 1. The array never contains just any of the other 1s.

An easy way to do this is to loop over all elements in a list and test if they are equal to N.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 8, 1]

def count_val(array, n):
    if len(array) == 0:
        return 0
    count=0
    for i in array:
        if i==n:
            count += 1
    return count

print(count_val(array, 1))
```

This returns 5.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The idea is to use a recursion not a loop. I know how to do that in an iterative way.