# Python Recursive calls not updating global variable

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion, global

I'm trying to implement a partial brute force approach in python for [Leetcode Beautiful Arrangements](https://leetcode.com/problems/beautiful-arrangement/). I'm struggling to update my "**counter**" variable during the recursive calls.

I've tried multiple approaches with global variables and passing it in as a function parameter, no matter what I've done, I'm not getting the correct return value even though the **if L == len(numbers)** condition is met.

```
class Solution:
    
    def countArrangement(self, n: int) -> int:

      def count_beautiful_arranges(N: int, counter):
            numbers = [0]*N

            # start index at 1
            # loop creates the array of 1 to N for initial list
            for i in range(1, N+1):
                numbers[(i-1)] = i
            
            # call recursive permutation function
            permutation(numbers, 0, counter)

            return counter
        
        def permutation(numbers: list, L: int, counter):
            
            # check each recursive call
            #print(L)
            #print(len(numbers))
            
            if L == len(numbers):
                counter = counter + 1
            
            for j in range(L, len(numbers)):

                swap(numbers, j, L)
                if numbers[L] % (L+1) == 0 or (L+1) % numbers[L] == 0:
                    permutation(numbers, L+1, counter)
                swap(numbers, j, L)
            
        
        def swap(numbers: list, x: int, y: int):
            
            #pythonic code
            numbers[x], numbers[y] = numbers[y], numbers[x]
            
        
        count_beautiful_arranges(n, 0)
```

Comment: For this problem, use `permutations` method will end up Time Exceed, it just takes tool long.

Comment: This is a partial permutation brute force, it will pass the test because it stops generating the permutation as soon as one of the conditions is violated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using Python's ability to attach a variable to a function. with
<Function_Name>. method I was able to attach a counter and increment it in the recursive stack.

I declared permutation.countser before calling the recursive functions then returned the value after the calls were completed.

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41203348/14650328) helped me.

```
        def count_beautiful_arranges(N: int, counter):
            numbers = [0]*N

            # start index at 1
            # loop creates the array of 1 to N for initial list
            for i in range(1, N+1):
                numbers[(i-1)] = i
            
            permutation(numbers, 0)

            
        def permutation(numbers: list, L: int):

            if L == len(numbers):
                permutation.countser += 1
            
            for j in range(L, len(numbers)):

                swap(numbers, j, L)
                if numbers[L] % (L+1) == 0 or (L+1) % numbers[L] == 0:
                    permutation(numbers, L+1)
                swap(numbers, j, L)
                

        
        def swap(numbers: list, x: int, y: int):
            
            #pythonic code
            numbers[x], numbers[y] = numbers[y], numbers[x]
            
        
        permutation.countser = 0
        count_beautiful_arranges(n, 0)
        return permutation.countser
```