# Create decorator for recursion count

Tags: python, function, recursion, attributes, decorator

I need to create a decorator to call Ackermann function and write down its attributes: the number of recursions and execution time.

I tried the below code but it works wrong.

Could anyone help?

```
def visualise(func):
    visualise.level = 0
    @wraps (func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         start=time.perf_counter()
         visualise.level += 1
         calls = func(*args, **kwargs)
         visualise.level -= 1
         last_time_taken=time.perf_counter()-start
         setattr(func,'calls',calls)
         setattr(func,'last_time_taken',last_time_taken)
         print(last_time_taken)
         return calls
    return wrapper

@visualise
def ackermann(n, m):
    ...

ackermann(2, 2)
ackermann.last_time_taken
ackermann.calls
```

The result should be `ackermann.last_time_taken = 0.00000034` seconds (for example) and `ackermann.calls = 7`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and good question in general, but in the future (or [edit] further), it's good to state the actual error, `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'last_time_taken'` rather than "it works wrong", so that we're on the exact same page and solving the same problem together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal version of your code:

```py
from functools import wraps


def visualise(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        setattr(func, "bar", 42) # or func.bar = 42

    return wrapper


@visualise
def foo():
    ...


foo()
print(foo.bar) # => AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

How to debug?

We can start by making sure the attribute can really be set on a function:

```py
from functools import wraps


def visualise(func):
    setattr(func, "bar", 42)
    return func


@visualise
def foo():
    ...


foo()
print(foo.bar) # => 42
```

OK, that worked. Next, let's go back to the wrapped code and make sure we're adding the property to the correct function:

```py
from functools import wraps


def visualise(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(2, func) # => 2 <function foo at 0x00000248F38EFA30>
        setattr(func, "bar", 42)

    print(1, wrapper) # => 1 <function foo at 0x00000248F38EFAC0>
    return wrapper


@visualise
def foo():
    ...


foo()
print(3, foo) # => 3 <function foo at 0x00000248F38EFAC0>
print(foo.bar) # => AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

There's the problem; you're adding the property to the original function, but trying to access the property on the decorated function. That's a totally different object.

Fix it:

```py
from functools import wraps


def visualise(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        setattr(wrapper, "bar", 42) # wrapper, not func

    return wrapper


@visualise
def foo():
    ...


foo()
print(foo.bar) # => 42
```

---

See also [Counting recursive calls of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203214/counting-recursive-calls-of-a-function/68277422#68277422)